# launch application from python3 then continue other code

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

The problem I need to solve is how to launch a program from python3 in such a way that control is passed back to the python script to do other things.  I have experimented with os.system and subprocess.call as so

```
import subprocess, os
os.system('gedit&')
subprocess.call(['gedit','&'])
```

both of which seem to wait for gedit, in a sence like it is waiting on some sort of stream from gedit.  If I type gedit & at the terminal I get the desired effect outside of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen(['gedit'])
```

`subprocess.call` essentially does the above line, but then calls `communicate` on the resulting object, which waits for it to exit. Since you don't want to wait, you can just *not* call `communicate`, and the process will be created, leaving your process to go on its merry way.

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for, Thank you.  I should have done more research into subprocess.  My apologies.  Your help was greatly apreciated.